# How to create calendar from json using http request

Tags: mysql, json, flutter, calendar

This my data model

```
class Datum { String id; String title; DateTime date;String lokasi; String kelab; String fakulti; DateTime selesai;
Datum({
this.id,
this.title,
this.date,
this.lokasi,
this.kelab,
this.fakulti,
this.selesai, });







  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
    id: json["ID_mohon"],
    date: DateTime.parse(json["mula"]),
    title: json["nama_aktiviti"],
    lokasi: json["lokasi"],);`
```

This my method fetch

```
Future<Map<DateTime, List>> getTask() async {
Map<DateTime, List> mapFetch = {};

await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {});






var res = await http.get("http://192.168.43.105/aktivitiKita/api/lihatAktiviti.php"); if (res.statusCode == 200) {
 Event event = jsonDecode(res.body);
for (int i = 0; i < event.data.length; i++) {
  mapFetch[event.data[i].date] = [event.data[i].title];
}

return mapFetch;
} }
```

and now im getting an error of type list os not a subtype of type 'Event'. 
im using a mysql phpmyadmin to fetch the data into the table calendar.

Comment: I can't provide a full answer right now, but you are declaring the response body as a single event. Your map form is <DateTime, List> when it should be something else.

Comment: Does i need to change the map form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to create list of map from json data then you should make following changes.

```
List<Map<DateTime, List>> mapFetch = [];
```

Replace Following line:

```
mapFetch[event.data[i].date] = [event.data[i].title];
```

With this:

```
 mapFetch.add({event.data[i].date:[event.data[i].title]});
```

Comment: it give me an error of mapFetch that is  The argument type 'Set<Object>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<DateTime, List>'.

Comment: that was my mistake i mistakenly added (,) insted of (:) in map.add method. can you try now ?

Comment: do i need to change the declaration of  Future<Map<DateTime, List>> getTask() async{}?

Comment: You have to change to Future<List<Map<DateTime, List>>>.

Comment: It says The element type 'Map<DateTime, List>' can't be assigned to the map key type 'DateTime'.

Comment: i updated code. if doesn’t work then please add  "print(event.data);" and "print(event.data[i].date);"

Comment: i want to ask a question  on how to display the data iam using the  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      getTask().then((val) => setState(() {
            _events = val;
          }));
  
    });

Comment: It is not best way to print async data. You should use futurebuilder. Does my answer work for you? If work then mark my answer.